# Limiting the length and input mask in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I need to limit the number of digits allowed in my TextBox in C#.

I also need to create the validation so that it will resemble a mobile number, meaning it must begin with 07 and have a total of 11 digits.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using WPF, winforms or html?

Comment: winforms, visual studio 2012 for c#

Comment: trying anything i can, should just be validation of limit of characters and validation of first two characts must begin with "" but i am unsure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) to provide a controlled input value. A "07" followed by 11 digit mask would be `\0\700000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code as example, so, I would type mine.

To limit the number of characters you should type this code:

```
private bool Validation()
{
    if (textBox.Text.Length != 11)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Text in textBox must have 11 characters", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        textBox.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want that text in your textBox begin with "07", you should type this code:

```
private bool Validation()
{
    string s = textBox.Text;
    string s1 = s.Substring(0, 1); // First number in brackets is from wich position you want to cut string, the second number is how many characters you want to cut
    string s2 = s.Substring(1, 1);
    if (s1 != "0" || s2 != "7")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Number must begin with 07", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        textBox.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can merge this in one method ofcource, and you can call it where ever you want. If you want to call in some method(for example when you click on accept button) just type this code:

```
private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Validation() == false) return;
}
```

Comment: The condition in the second `Validation` method is wrong. Not to mention creating two string instances each containing one character is both harder to read and creates unnecessary objects on the heap. I'd also think about whether it is a good idea to have a method called `Validation` returning a bool that shows a mesage box. Doesn't feel very reusable...

Comment: I saw that I accidentally type && instead of ||, now it is working. I am using validations like this and it is working... If you have some other code to share with us, I will be glad to try it.:)